# Run a another within script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to run another terminal within script and wait for function to execute on that terminal
before proceeding next command in shell script. Scenario is as like below

script.sh

```
!/bin/sh

...
...
gnome-terminal --working-directory=#{image_path} -e ./test.sh # execute test.sh script on  another terminal

./switch 0 0 # I have to execute this command after test.sh script gets completed on another terminal

...
...
```

Here problem is. test.sh script is not gets executed fully and returned back immediately to parent script and executes `./switch 0 0` command. As this `./switch 0 0` command depends on `test.sh` script completion, my script gets failed.

Regards
Manish B.

Comment: I kind of have to ask: why does that `test.sh` have to run in a separate terminal?

Comment: Look at the output of `gnome-terminal --help` and see of there's something there

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a switch in gnome-terminal that can make it run synchronously, but you can use xterm for that. Xterm won't go to the background unlike other terminals:

```
( D=$(pwd); cd "$image_path"; xterm -e "$D/test.sh" )
./switch 0 0
```